# C# Blurry results when drawing vector image into bitmap

Tags: c#, image, svg, rendering

I'm currently trying to compile a small image from multiple rendered images.
One of the images is a generated QR code which displays nicely on the end result.
The other images are rendered from vector images, C# requires me to render them into Bitmap objects. This process itself goes just fine, if i export these images they are exactly as they should be.

The problem is, if i want to add these bitmaps into another bitmap(in which i need to rotate them) they become blurry. They do need to be resized to fit so this might also be an issue.

This is the rendering of the QR code

```
QrEncoder encoder = new QrEncoder();
        QrCode qrCode;

        GraphicsRenderer gRenderer = new GraphicsRenderer(
            new FixedCodeSize(330, QuietZoneModules.Two),
            Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);


ms = new MemoryStream();
            encoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel = ErrorCorrectionLevel.H;
            encoder.TryEncode(id + ":" + i, out qrCode);

            gRenderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ImageFormat.Png, ms);
            Image bmp = Image.FromStream(ms);


            Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width + 160, bmp.Height + 160);
```

This is the rendering of the vector images:

```
SvgDocument svgDoc2 = SvgDocument.Open(Application.StartupPath + @"\resources\logo2.svg");
        svgDoc2.Width = new SvgUnit(svgDoc2.Width.Type, svgDoc2.Width * 2);
        svgDoc2.Height = new SvgUnit(svgDoc2.Height.Type, svgDoc2.Height * 2);
        //svgDoc2.Transforms = new SvgTransformCollection();
        //svgDoc2.Transforms.Add(new SvgScale(2, 2));

        Bitmap logo2 = new Bitmap((int)svgDoc2.Width.Value, (int)svgDoc2.Height.Value);

        svgDoc2.Draw(logo2);
```

And this is the drawing of the logo's

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
            {
                g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.None;
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Default;
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.DrawImage(bmp, 80, 80);

                g.TranslateTransform(newBmp.Width / 2, newBmp.Height / 2);

                g.DrawImage(logo, -(logo.Width / 2) + 64, newBmp.Height / 2 - 80, 284, 78);
                g.RotateTransform(90);
                g.DrawImage(logo2, -(logo2.Width / 2) + 64, newBmp.Width / 2 - 80, 284, 76);
                g.RotateTransform(90);
                g.DrawImage(logo, -(logo.Width / 2) + 64, newBmp.Height / 2 - 80, 284, 78);
                g.RotateTransform(90);
                g.DrawImage(logo2, -(logo2.Width / 2) + 64, newBmp.Width / 2 - 80, 284, 76);
                g.RotateTransform(90);
```

Note that i have tried to work with the pixeloffset, interpolation and smoothing mode but no matter what the combination of these 3, i can't get a perfect result.

Does anyone know the correct way to render this and get pixel perfect images as a result.

Comment: Have you tried moving the resizing to the end of the chain?

Comment: Yes i have indeed tried that, does not seem to be the problem